# "sending" data from html to javascript for a random name generator

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm building a random name generator that pulls from an array depending what checkboxes are checked. I'm having trouble connecting the html form to the js document and I'm pretty new to this so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var arrayFemme = ["Guinevere", "Luna", "Florence", "Caitlin", "Alexandria",      "Charlie"];
    var arrayMasc = ["Flynn", "Darren", "Alexander", "Charles"];
    var arrayUni = ["London", "Paris", "Alex", "Charlie"];
    var arrayAll = arrayFemme.concat(arrayMasc).concat(arrayUni);

    var arrayFirstLetters = [];

    //Selecting Name's Gender and preffered first letter
    var arrayGenders = ["a", "m", "f", "u"];
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    function generator(){
        
        function formInput() {
            var selected = document.getElementById("genderForm").gender; 
            
            for(var i = 0; i<selected.length; i++){
                if(selected[i].checked == true){
                    alert (arrayGenders[i])
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("pickGender").focus
                }
            };
            
        };
         function test(){
           document.getElementById('submit').submit();
           alert("why does nothing work?!");
       };
```

```html
    <!-- FORM -->
            <div id="form">
                <form name="genderForm" method="get" id="genderForm">
                    <h1>Name Generator</h1>
                    <p id="pickGender">Preffered Name's Gender:</br>
                        (Please select atleast one option)
                    </p>

                    <input type="checkbox" name="Gender" value="All"> All the names!
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Gender" value="Masculine"> Masculine
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Gender" value="Feminine"> Feminine
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Gender" value="Unisex"> Unisex</br>

                    <p>Preferred First Letter: (If applicable) <input type="text" name="firstLetter" maxlength="1" size="1">
                    </p>
        
                   
                        <button class="optionsButtonMore">Advanced Options</button><br>
                        <input type=submit value="Gimme a name!" class="submit" id="submit" onclick="generator();">
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I have literally no idea what's wrong and any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Use a code snip for basic html and js so we can help you better.

Comment: @wobbles at the risk of sounding like an idiot, how do I do that? :')

Comment: It is one of the options in the editor when writing your question. Edit your ques and mouse over the icons till you see code snip, you then place the relevant parts in there respective fields. It allows us to look at and run your code on the fly without having to create a fiddle.

Comment: @wobbles I did it haha

Comment: You have some syntax errors for starters, you do not need ; after }.

Comment: you also have functions defined inside functions o.O ?

Comment: @Wobbles I did say that I literally just started, like, this morning :')

Comment: conceptually its not bad, you just need some syntax practice.

Comment: besides the syntax issues, it looks like you want to be doing form validation, in which case you should subscribe to the onSubmit event of the form and not the onClick event of the button as the prior can stop the form submission if the form does not validate. see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp for help

Comment: I can't figure out why it isn't working? Like I assumed once I had linked to the JS file in the HTML and started calling IDs in the JS file it would all just work?

Comment: Well **nothing** will work with syntax errors. If you pull up your browsers console you will see the errors displayed there.

Comment: @wobbles yeah I've gone though correcting things haha, thanks for the help!